# Weird padding behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

In my application a try to position 8 small squares around one big one. See image below.

[image]

```
<UserControl
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ResizerStyle" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Padding.Top, ElementName=border, Mode=Default}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Padding.Top, ElementName=border, Mode=Default}"/>
    </Style>
    <Thickness x:Key="ScalersSize">8</Thickness>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Panel.ZIndex="-1000" Padding="{DynamicResource ScalersSize}" Background="#00000000">
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFC00000"/>
        </Border>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="SizeNS" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="SizeNESW" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Cursor="SizeNS" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <local:Scaler VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Cursor="SizeNESW" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <local:Scaler HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Cursor="SizeWE" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
        <local:Scaler HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Cursor="SizeWE" Style="{StaticResource ResizerStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the following renders red 62x62 square. But as far as I know 80 - 8 * 2  = 64. So why it is rendered it as 62 by 62 square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting the 80 from since it's not anywhere in your XAML but I assume that's supposed to be the size of the outer UserControl. In your calculation you missed one part: the border itself. You have the BorderThickness set to 1 which means there is a 1 unit area on all sides being held for the border line but not being shown because there isn't a BorderBrush set. So the actual size is 80 - (8 * 2) - (1 * 2) = 62

Comment: Right! But I thought that the border is rendered on the inside, isn't it? So, if I have UserControl with width and height 50 and 5 border, it is going to be 60 by 60?

Comment: The Border is an external container of its child content so it takes all the space it needs first. Since the red square is the Rectangle inside the Border its size is determined by the combination of all of <Border container size (Grid)> - <Border Margin> - <Border Thickness> - <Border Padding> - <Rectangle Margin>